# Sending data to EventHub from Asp.Net site

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-eventhub

I have an Azure `EventHub` that I send data to. If I use the following code in a console application (framework 4.6.1), it runs perfectly.

```
        eventHubClient = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(myConnString);

        Console.WriteLine("Client Created");

        var sender = eventHubClient.CreatePartitionSender("1");

        var message = $"Message";

        Console.WriteLine($"Sending message: {message}");
        var eventData = new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));

        if (!sender.SendAsync(eventData).Wait(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000)) )
        {
           int a = 0;
        }
```

However, if I put it in an `Asp.Net` application (targeting framework 4.6.1) either running in `IIS-Express` or `IIS`, it times out every time.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why are you forcing all items into Partion 1? I'm using this approach, but in an async method that uses await - the Wait for 10 seconds looks suspicious - I would remove it.

Comment: @SimonW I am not forcing into one partition, this was example code. I have 5 partitions that I send events to. As for the wait, that is not a `Wait for 10 seconds`, that provides a timeout for the call.

Comment: If you remove the 10 second timeout does it succeed? Is this being invoked in a call to a Controller or similar? If so is that Controller Action set to run in an async fashion?

Comment: @SimonW I am posted what I did to solve it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that when you call use an `async` method in a non-async context in an Asp.Net application, it causes some sorted of dead-lock.

In my case, I need to know if it has timed out so I couldn't just leave it to run asynchronously and there was work that I needed done after the `async` call was completed as well as if it failed.

This is what I did

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    if (!sender.SendAsync(eventData).Wait(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000)) )
        {
           int a = 0;
        }
});
```

This allows me to handle both timeouts as well as success. Unfortunately it was not an option to make the entire call stack `async` so using `await` was out of the question.

TL;DR : Calling `.Wait()` in an ASP.NET application can cause a deadlock.